# Monitoring several delayed jobs using god

Tags: ruby-on-rails, god

So far I've been monitoring a single delayed job using god and its been working great.
I want to start monitoring several delayed jobs, how can I pass a parameter when stating god that will indicate how many delayed_jobs god should monitor/start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a predefined variable in the shell before call god, and in your god config look for the contents of that shell variable to know how many jobs to start.  You would probably want a default value for that variable.

Something like:
`$ env GOD_JOBS=3 god ...`

And then use the below in your god config:
`ENV['GOD_JOBS']`